# OWASP ZAP How to send POST request through ZAP API

Tags: owasp, zap

I am running ZAP in demon mode and I want to send a POST request for spider and active scans. I am using the sendRequest API and the form method is POST.

Problem: the requests are sent to the server without the request body.

[image]

How should I build the POST request to make this work?

Comment: Manish, did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Separate the data from the headers with 2 pairs of CRLF (\r\n\r\n) as per the HTTP spec.

Comment: No Simon I am passing integer value in content length. The problem I am facing is to segregate headers, query string parameters and form data part in  sendRequest API. Can you send me a sample POST request or a post request template for sendRequest API so that I can pass the parameters based on the template of Send request API